# Why 2 levels of indirection in definition of macro ## operation

Tags: c++, c, concatenation, c-preprocessor

In the macro definitions below, there're 2 levels of indirection before the real pasting operation:

```
#define MACRO_JOIN(a, b)  MACRO_JOIN1(a, b)
#define MACRO_JOIN1(a, b) MACRO_JOIN2(a, b)
#define MACRO_JOIN2(a, b) a##b
```

I know that we need `MACRO_JOIN1` because it has no pasting or stringifying so that its arguments can be expanded first.

But what exactly is the purpose of the second indirection `MACRO_JOIN`? In what situations `MACRO_JOIN` will work but `MACRO_JOIN1` will fail?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Forcing an additional expansion can make a difference where the initial expansion results in something that can be expanded further. A trivial example, given:

```
#define MACRO(x) x
#define EXPAND(x) x
#define NOEXPAND()
```

is:

```
MACRO NOEXPAND() (123)
```

This expands to `MACRO (123)`. On the other hand, if you force an additional expansion, like so:

```
EXPAND(MACRO NOEXPAND() (123))
```

results in:

```
123
```

Normally, forcing additional expansions like this is unnecessary: any macro definitions that would cause this to make any difference are generally considered poor style anyway. But with certain specific inputs, it may be useful.

So for a concrete example with your `MACRO_JOIN`:

```
MACRO_JOIN(123, MACRO NOEXPAND() (456)) // expands to 123456
MACRO_JOIN1(123, MACRO NOEXPAND() (456)) // expands to 123MACRO (456)
```

Comment: Amazing explanation! I must try these special test cases on my cpp implementations...

Comment: I see. I was thinking that its purpose would be like to "force" something, but I never thought about this kind of uses. Another question: In your example, the macro `NOEXPAND()` is almost useless. Is there any case where we can make use of it?

Comment: @PJ.Hades Like I said, any macro definitions where it makes a difference is generally considered poor style anyway. Any example I could come up with would be just as useless as `NOEXPAND()`. So I'd say don't worry about it unless you happen to actually find a use case for it with macro definitions you're using.